# Partial sum projection of a cauchy sequence is cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces

I am studying 'Topics in Banach Space Theory' by Fernando Albiac and Kalton.

> Theorem $1.1.3$ Let $X$ be a (separable) Banach space. A sequence $(e_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $X$ is a Schauder basis for $X$ if and only if $(e_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a basis for $X$.

Proof:  Let us assume that $(e_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a basis for $X$ and introduce the partial sum projection $(S_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ associated to $(e_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ defined by $S_0 = 0$ and for $n \geq 1$, 
$$S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^ne_k^{\#}(x)e_k$$

(Here $e_k^{\#}$ is a functional on $X$. It is well-defined due to uniqueness of coefficients of $x$.)

Suppose $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X,\| \cdot \|).$ Of course, $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is convergent to some $x \in X$ in the norm $\| \cdot \|.$ **Notice that for each fixed $k$ the sequence $(S_kx_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is convergent in the norm $\| \cdot \|$ to some $y_k \in X.$**

Question: How to prove the bolded sentence? My thought is: Since $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy, then we have $\| \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e_k^{\#}(x_n)e_k - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}e_k^{\#}(x_m)e_k \| < \varepsilon.$ Then for each fixed $k$, we have $\| \sum_{i=1}^ke_i^{\#}(x_n)e_i - \sum_{i=1}^ke_i^{\#}(x_m)e_i \| = \| \sum_{i=1}^ke_i^{\#}(x_n - x_m)e_i \| \leq \| e_i \|_{\infty} \| \sum_{i=1}^ke_i^{\#}(x_n-x_m) \|$. I stuck here.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you copied one important sentence wrongly. It says in the book that

> Suppose that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(X,\color{red}{|||\cdot|||})$

where
$$
|||x|||=\sup_{k\ge 1}\|S_kx\|.
$$
It means that 
$$
|||x_n-x_m|||=\sup_{k\ge 1}\|S_k(x_n-x_m)\|=\sup_{k\ge 1}\|S_k(x_n)-S_k(x_m)\|\to 0.
$$
Clearly, it ensures that $\{S_k(x_n)\}$ is Cauchy sequence in the original norm for every $k$, thus, converges to some $y_k$.

Comment: But I do not know $\| e_i^{\#} \|$ is bounded.

Comment: @Idonknow I've redone the answer after having looked at the book.

Comment: How do we conclude that $\sup_{k \geq 1}\| S_k(x_n) - S_k(x_m) \|$ converges to $0$? Is it because $(x_n)$ is Cauchy in $||| \cdot |||$?

Comment: @Idonknow Right, Cauchy sequence means that the length between $x_n$ and $x_m$ vanishes when $n,m\to +\infty$.